# Criteria condition; logical conversion (a+b)(c+d) to ((w ? x) ? y) ? z

Tags: php, mysql, yii, logic

I'm trying to add the following conditions in Yii:

```
$a = [1,2,3];
$b = [1,2,3];

$criteria->addCondition('A IS NULL', 'AND');
$criteria->addInCondition('A', $a, 'OR');
$criteria->addCondition('B IS NULL', 'AND');
$criteria->addInCondition('B', $b, 'OR');
```

I was hoping the following MySQL would come out:

```
WHERE (A IS NULL OR A IN (1,2,3)) 
  AND (B IS NULL OR B IN (1,2,3))
```

But alas out came:

```
WHERE (((A IS NULL) OR A IN (1,2,3)) AND B IS NULL) OR B IN (1,2,3)
```

Basically, for anyone who doesn't know yii, I'd like to rewrite `(a+b)(c+d)` to `((w ? x) ? y) ? z`, is this possible without repeating any conditions? Or do I need to think about an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you are asking with the rewrite `(a+b)(c+d)` to `((w ? x) ? y) ? z` thing, but if you want to create the following condition:

```
WHERE (A IS NULL OR A IN (1,2,3)) 
  AND (B IS NULL OR B IN (1,2,3))
```

Then just use this code:

```
$a = [1,2,3];
$b = [1,2,3];

$criteria1 = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria1->addCondition('A IS NULL');
$criteria1->addInCondition('A', $a,'OR');

$criteria2 = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria2->addCondition('B IS NULL');
$criteria2->addInCondition('B', $b,'OR');

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition($criteria1->condition);
$criteria->addCondition($criteria2->condition);

$criteria->params = array_merge($criteria1->params,$criteria2->params);
```

The resulting condition is given via

```
echo $criteria->condition;
```

as

```
((A IS NULL) OR (A IN (:ycp0, :ycp1, :ycp2))) 
AND ((B IS NULL) OR (B IN (:ycp3, :ycp4, :ycp5)))
```

(The `ycp#` are the parameterized values specified in `$a` and `$b`.)

Comment: Like it! Simple and effective.